# Non-Renewing Subscription Already purchased alert track

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, ios8, non-renewing-subscription

I am implementing Non-renewing subscription IAP in my app where I am making server implementation to expire a subscription. I am stuck when I click on a subscription I already have bought, It shows a dialog, **"This In-App purchase has already been bought. It will be restored for free."** with OK button. I have two questions here:

1. Sometime it shows the above dialog but sometimes it shows **"Tap buy to renew or extend it."** dialog. Can anyone tell me whats reason behind this? Or it is just a Sandbox issue. ([This screenshot from another thread.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9vUH.png))
2. When I get **"This In-App purchase has already been bought. It will be restored for free."** alert, how i can stop activity indicator? Is there a delegate method to track this?

I could not found but is there anything new came in **iOS 8**?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem in iOS 8 sandbox with Consumable product type. Bought it once, can't buy it again... even though it's clearly stated that it's a consumable. Weird.

Comment: I have the same problem in iOS 8 sandbox

Comment: Facing same issue in Non-Consumable IAP also. But the app has been submitted and approved by iTunes guys.

Comment: Hi - Were you able to solve the #2? I am facing exact same problem. I am not getting callback, if the product is already bought, and restored..it is frustrating. Please let me know

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. For a non-renewable subscription, the correct dialog is **"Tap buy to renew or extend it."**. The reason for this is that once a non-consumable product is owned, it is owned permanently; hence the "renew or extend" language.
2. You are getting this dialog because you are attempting to purchase the same product again before completing the transaction on the *app's side*. The App Store has approved the transaction and sent you a transaction ID, but you have not confirmed that you have delivered the promised content/access. Thus, the transaction is left in the `approved` state. The transaction remains tied to the app until you finish it.

See ["Finishing the Transaction" in Apple's (confusing, convoluted) documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW10).

Comment: for question 2, I know the problem but how to track this dialog, because the app may still display a activityIndicator to show the status is still processing.

Comment: Hey, did you get luck to resolve this issue, are you able to remove the activityIndicator?

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem in consumable IAP, and I have called the function `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]`. Then I found that there is a exception occurred in a function before the call, then I exchange the position of two function, the problem is solved now.

Comment: can you explain where to catch the exception.

Comment: Hi - I a facing the same problem. Where did you call that method? please help